# JavaMail - could not get body of text/plain message

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am writing a pop3 client using JavaMail to retrieve mails. But, I could not retrieve the body of the text/plain encoded mail messages.

The mail.getContent() is not fetching the body of the message. But mail.writeTo(System.out) is printing the complete mail data including the envelope information.

Is there any way to fetch only the body of the mail message?

Thanks!

Update: From the debug watch, I can see that mail.getContent() is only returning "\r\n".

Solution:
Seems like the problem is with mails sent directly from telnet session. The body of the mail is fetched propertly for mails sent from a smtp client program.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail is expecting a blank line (CRLF CRLF) to terminate the header block.  When you enter the message via telnet, you're sending your system newline (which is probably just LF) at the end of each line you enter.  So my guess is that JavaMail doesn't see the header/body separator it's expecting, and thus it's just tacking your "body" lines onto the end of its header block as malformed headers.